# I am getting this error "AttributeError: 'HalfSquaredError' object has no attribute 'get_init_raw_predictions'" in my Gradient Boosting Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

My code worked excellently before I added in Gradient Boosting to my testing site. It show me this error `AttributeError: 'HalfSquaredError' object has no attribute 'get_init_raw_predictions'` on Line `--> 142 ytest_pred = best_rf_model.predict(xtest_scaled)`.

This is my input for GB Model

```
[[-0.67788321 -0.23682976]
 [-0.67788321 -0.28130008]
 [-0.67788321 -0.34800556]
 [-0.67788321 -0.43694619]
 [-0.67788321 -0.48141651]
 [-0.67788321 -0.45918135]
 [-0.67788321 -0.43694619]
 [-0.67788321 -0.45918135]
 [-0.67788321 -0.48141651]
 [-0.67788321 -0.48141651]
 [-0.67788321 -0.52588683]
 [-0.67788321 -0.57035715]
 [-0.67788321 -0.61482746]
 [-0.67788321 -0.61482746]
 [-0.67788321 -0.61482746]
 [-0.62843324 -0.65929778]
 [-0.28756454 -0.54812199]
 [ 0.28879162 -0.28130008]
 [ 0.88939267  0.07446246]
 [ 1.4556668   0.45246016]
 [ 1.98785406  0.76375239]
 [ 2.43578434  1.16398525]
 [ 2.76225014  1.49751263]
 [ 3.0051791   1.80880486]
 [ 3.20249887  2.09786193]
 [ 3.37029269  2.36468383]
 [ 3.54024694  2.49809479]
 [ 3.64442794  2.49809479]
 [ 3.64226751  2.49809479]
 [ 3.45863049  2.49809479]
 [ 3.01502109  2.49809479]
 [ 2.48163358  2.49809479]
 [ 2.00297711  2.49809479]
 [ 1.52672112  2.49809479]
 [ 1.03750252  2.49809479]
 [ 0.55260479  2.49809479]
 [ 0.092192    2.45362447]
 [-0.29836672  2.34244867]
 [-0.5830641   2.05339161]
 [-0.67788321  1.45304232]
 [-0.67788321  0.98610398]
 [-0.67788321  0.76375239]
 [-0.67788321  0.60810628]
 [-0.67788321  0.49693048]
 [-0.67788321  0.38575469]
 [-0.67788321  0.25234373]
 [-0.67788321  0.1634031 ]
 [-0.67788321  0.0522273 ]]
```

This is my testing code

```
# %%
# Importing necessary libraries
import os
import warnings
from datetime import datetime

import joblib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Ignore specific UserWarnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
date_variable = '20240306'  # Date variable changable
# model = "randomForest"
# model = "ridge"
model = "gradientBoosting"
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

if model == "randomForest":
    outlier_dict = np.load('outlier_imputer_dict.npy',
                            allow_pickle=True).item()
    scaler = joblib.load('scaler_ridge.pkl')
    best_rf_model = joblib.load('pv_rf_model.pkl')
elif model == "ridge":
    outlier_dict = np.load('outlier_imputer_dict.npy',
                            allow_pickle=True).item()
    scaler = joblib.load('scaler.pkl')
    best_rf_model = joblib.load('pv_ridge_model.pkl')
elif model == "gradientBoosting":
    outlier_dict = np.load('outlier_imputer_dict.npy',
                            allow_pickle=True).item()
    scaler = joblib.load('scaler_gb.pkl')
    best_rf_model = joblib.load('pv_gb_model.pkl')
    print(best_rf_model)


base_directory = r'C:\Users\Chew\Desktop\Internship\Project\PV Power Forecasting\SiteName\Test Data'

# Specify the directory containing all CSV files
csv_directory = os.path.join(base_directory, date_variable)

# Function to impute outliers in the test data


def outlier_imputer(df):
    for var in df.columns[3:]:
        df.loc[df[df[var] > outlier_dict[var]['99th']].index,
               var] = outlier_dict[var]['99th']
        df.loc[df[df[var] < outlier_dict[var]['1st']].index,
               var] = outlier_dict[var]['1st']
    return df


# Specify the directory to store predicted files
if model == 'randomForest':
    predicted_folder = os.path.join(csv_directory, 'predicted_files_RF')
elif model == 'ridge':
    predicted_folder = os.path.join(csv_directory, 'predicted_files_Ridge')
elif model == 'gradientBoosting':
    predicted_folder = os.path.join(csv_directory, 'predicted_files_GB')

# Specify the directory to store predicted files
os.makedirs(predicted_folder, exist_ok=True)
rmse = []


# -------------------------NEED TO CHANGE TO TIARCO ACTUAL PV---------------------------
# Loop through all CSV files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(csv_directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv") and filename.startswith("2024"):
        file_path = os.path.join(csv_directory, filename)

        # Load the test data
        dftest = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='unicode_escape')
        # Drop rows with all NaN values
        dftest = dftest.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

        # Convert the 'Time' column to datetime format
        dftest['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dftest['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        # Set the 'Time' column as the index
        dftest.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

        # Resample the data with a 30-minute interval and take the mean of the values
        dftest = dftest.resample('30T').mean()

        # Reset the index to get 'Time' back as a column
        dftest.reset_index(inplace=True)
        # Check if 'CY-Handee Rubber Moulding Sdn Bhd(63171)/Plant Power(kW)' column exists
        if 'PV' not in dftest.columns:
            # Find the additional CSV file based on the specified naming convention
            additional_csv_file = [f for f in os.listdir(csv_directory) if f.startswith(
                "actual_pv") and f.endswith(".csv")]

            if additional_csv_file:
                additional_csv_file = os.path.join(
                    csv_directory, additional_csv_file[0])
                additional_data = pd.read_csv(additional_csv_file)
                dftest['PV'] = additional_data[
                    'solar_kW']
                # Save the updated CSV file
                # dftest.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

        # Convert 'Time' column to datetime
        dftest['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
            dftest['Time'], infer_datetime_format=True)

        # Split into 'Date' and 'Time' columns
        dftest['Date'] = dftest['Datetime'].dt.date
        dftest['Time'] = dftest['Datetime'].dt.time

        # Rename columns for clarity
        for col in dftest.columns:
            if col.startswith('Radiation'):
                dftest.rename(
                    columns={col: 'Transient-radiation'}, inplace=True)
            elif col.startswith('Temperature'):
                dftest.rename(
                    columns={col: 'Ambient Temperature'}, inplace=True)

        # Reorder columns
        dftest = dftest[['Date', 'Time', 'Transient-radiation',
                         'Ambient Temperature', 'PV']]

        # Create a copy of the test data
        df_test = dftest.copy()
        # Apply outlier imputation on test data
        df_test = outlier_imputer(df_test)

        # Process the test features
        xtest_processed = df_test[[
            'Transient-radiation', 'Ambient Temperature']]
        # Use the same scaler as in training
        xtest_scaled = scaler.transform(xtest_processed)
        # Predict on the test set
        ytest_pred = best_rf_model.predict(xtest_scaled)

        # Calculate metrics on the test set
        rmse_test = mean_squared_error(
            df_test['PV'], ytest_pred, squared=False)
        r2_test = r2_score(df_test['PV'], ytest_pred)
        mae_test = mean_absolute_error(df_test['PV'], ytest_pred)

        # # Print metrics
        # print(f"R-squared on test set: {r2_test}")
        # print(f"Mean Absolute Error on test set: {mae_test}")
        # print(f"Mean RMSE on test set: {rmse_test}")
        rmse.append(rmse_test)

        # Add the predicted PV values to the DataFrame
        df_test['PV_Predicted'] = np.round(ytest_pred/1000, decimals=2)

        # Save the DataFrame with predicted values back to CSV
        predicted_csv_filename = f"predicted_{filename}"
        predicted_file_path = os.path.join(
            predicted_folder, predicted_csv_filename)
        df_test.to_csv(predicted_file_path, index=False)

# Do a print statement that shows testing done and save where
print(f"Testing done on {model} training set")
print(f"Testing done on {date_variable} and saved to {predicted_folder}")
# %%
# After scaling the test data, add print statements to check its shape
print("Shape of xtest_scaled:", xtest_scaled.shape)

# After loading the model, print its attributes and properties
print("Loaded model:", best_rf_model)
```

This is the complete error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\Chew\Desktop\Internship\Project\PV Power Forecasting\Tiarco\Model Testing.py:142
    140 xtest_scaled = scaler.transform(xtest_processed)
    141 # Predict on the test set
--> 142 ytest_pred = best_rf_model.predict(xtest_scaled)
    144 # Calculate metrics on the test set
    145 rmse_test = mean_squared_error(
    146     df_test['PV'], ytest_pred, squared=False)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_gb.py:1790, in GradientBoostingRegressor.predict(self, X)
   1786 X = self._validate_data(
   1787     X, dtype=DTYPE, order="C", accept_sparse="csr", reset=False
   1788 )
   1789 # In regression we can directly return the raw value from the trees.
-> 1790 return self._raw_predict(X).ravel()

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_gb.py:685, in BaseGradientBoosting._raw_predict(self, X)
    683 def _raw_predict(self, X):
    684     """Return the sum of the trees raw predictions (+ init estimator)."""
--> 685     raw_predictions = self._raw_predict_init(X)
    686     predict_stages(self.estimators_, X, self.learning_rate, raw_predictions)
    687     return raw_predictions

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_gb.py:678, in BaseGradientBoosting._raw_predict_init(self, X)
    674     raw_predictions = np.zeros(
    675         shape=(X.shape[0], self._loss.K), dtype=np.float64
    676     )
    677 else:
--> 678     raw_predictions = self._loss.get_init_raw_predictions(X, self.init_).astype(
    679         np.float64
    680     )
    681 return raw_predictions

AttributeError: 'HalfSquaredError' object has no attribute 'get_init_raw_predictions'
```

I also checked my saved model format `GradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.05, min_samples_leaf=4, min_samples_split=5, subsample=0.6)`
and it looks normal as usual when I do my training.

I have installed all the necessary libraries like pandas numpy scikit-learn. What could be the reason that it suddenly gave this error?

Comment: What version of `scikit-learn` are you using?

Comment: @rr_goyal
Name: scikit-learn
Version: 1.3.1

Comment: "Downgrading the version of sklearn to 0.20.2 gets rid of this error." from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14076) might help you.